# Windows mobile app List view carousel

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Am developing windows mobile app in 8.1. Looking for a control like List view carousel.

Only one item needs to be shown at a time. User needs to swipe to go next / previous item. Order will be highlighted in below **dots**

[image]

Comment: Tell us what you wrote so far; this is not a code-writing service-site

Comment: Not sure if this could help, but here is a nice example on how to create a looping items panel http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/04/16/winrt-create-a-custom-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use a flipview. Check this for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781233.aspx

Comment: FlipView doesn't let you have carousel mode and implementing it by your own will be a true pain. Trust me, I tried ;)

Comment: In the flipview template include a listview. Let the item in the listview be an ellipse. change the colour of the ellipse. It should give you the desired view

Comment: But flip view can't behave like a pivot and provide a carousel mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a control containing a Pivot with custom template for Image, header textblocks and other things you want and a LitView, also with custom template for showing which item is selected. It will need to change selected index according to pivot changes.
As Sjon wrote, nobody will code it for you so after my hints I think you should manage to build it.